# StrongSwan: manually expire security association

Tags: bash, ipsec, strongswan, openwrt

I am working on automating some software tests involving IPSec and StrongSwan. These tests basically apply a swanctl.conf file to two gateway machines, then establish a tunnel between them. It then checks that the tunnel is encrypted and reports performance. However, it doesn't clean up that well. The result is that my test boxes have a bunch of unused Security Associations that appear when running `ipsec statusall` that I cannot figure out how to get rid of. I don't want to wait for them to expire, but I am not aware of a way to manually expire/delete them. Does such a method exist?

Comment: Could you please provide more information on what you are doing and what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a potential solution.

Security Associations get deleted when IPsec restarts. If I want to be sure that I cleaned up everything (and it's fine to do this since these are test boxes that only I should be using anyway), I can simply call

`ipsec restart`

on each box. This'll flush the Security Associations and anything else that is potentially floating around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ip xfrm state` (`ip x s` - short version) subcommands.

First, check security associations with `ip x s ls`, and then remove it with `ip x s delete ...`.

Also there are commands to mass remove - `ip x s deleteall ...` and `ip x s flush`.